# What is the Big-O of these nested loops

Tags: algorithm, big-o

After solving a cp problem (implementation below), i had a difficult time doing the big O analysis, something (i thought) i was very comfortable with.
Here is the implementation:

```
    // argument arrays (alice and scores)

    // captures scores
    auto findRank = [&](int score, int lastRankIndex) {
        // resumes from last returned index
        for(auto i=lastRankIndex-1; i>=0; --i) {
            if(scores[i] == score) return i+1;
            else if(scores[i] > score) return i+2;
        }
        return 1;
    };
    vector<int> ranks;
    ranks.reserve(alice.size());
    int lastRankIndex = scores.size();

    // loop over alice
    for(const auto& a : alice) {
        ranks.push_back(findRank(a, lastRankIndex));
        lastRankIndex = ranks.back() - 1;
    }
```

The `findRank` lambda will (with the help of `lastRankIndex`) always resume at the **previously returned index**. It means the two arrays `alice` and `scores` which can in our case have different sizes, will be looped over only once.
What should be the big O in this case especially  when the inner loops array is bigger than the outer one ?

Comment: If your analysis suggests each array will looped only once, why would the answer not be that the complexity is linear?

Comment: Because the loops are nested. And in the case of a very big inner array and a relatively small outer one, on which array should the linearity depend ?